# Make a list from a dataframe: column A are variables and column B are associated with values in column C

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to parse a dataframe into a list format where column A is a a set of 'bins' that link to a set of bins in column B, where column C is the proportion that moves from bin A to bin B. It is easy to create the list format manually eg.

```r
df.list <- list() 
df.list$litter <- data.frame('lost'=50,'pot'=15,'pool'=35)
df.list$lost <- data.frame('pool'=30, 'pot'=10, 'lost'=60)
df.list$bin <- data.frame(uncollected=4, collected=96)
df.list$dump <- data.frame(litter=50, burn=20)
df.list$uncollected <- data.frame(litter=25, burn=55, dump=20)
df.list$collected <- data.frame(litter=3.7, dump=54.3, recycle=30, burn=12 )
```

but I have a large database and multiple years and multiple locations that is in csv format, where I need to separate each year and location and then make a list that looks like the below output for each year.

```r
> df.list
$litter
  lost pot pool
1   50  15   35

$lost
  pool pot lost
1   30  10   60

$bin
  uncollected collected
1           4        96

$dump
  litter burn
1     50   20

$uncollected
  litter burn dump
1     25   55   20

$collected
  litter dump recycle burn
1    3.7 54.3      30   12
```

I have tried other examples that have been posted but I can't figure out how to isolate each 'bin' in the **item** column and then nest the **node** and associated **value** within the item in a list format...
This is a simulation of the dataframe I am using:

```r
df <- data.frame(year=sort(c(rep(c(2010, 2011, 2012), 15))), 
                 item=c(rep(rep(c("litter", "lost", "bin", "uncollected", "collected"), c(3,3,2,3,4)),3)),
                 node=rep(c("lost",  "pot" , "pool", "pool" ,"pot" , "lost", "collected",  "uncollected",
                                 "litter", "burn" , "dump" , "litter" , "dump", "recycle", "burn"),3),
                 value=rep(c(50.0, 15.0 ,35.0, 30.0, 10.0, 60.0, 96.0,  4.0, 25.0, 55.0 , 20.0,  3.7, 54.3,30.0, 12.0),3))
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kind of hammered this into place, but this should do what you're asking.  I'm going back to clunky for loops here, but could be adapted with lapply to be more efficient i'm sure.

```
outlist <- list()
for(i in unique(df$year)){

  for(j in unique(df$item)){

    list.item.name <- paste(j,i,sep='.')

    tdf <- df[which(df$year==i & df$item==j),c('node','value')]
    newdf <- data.frame(t(tdf))
    names(newdf) <- newdf$node
    rownames(newdf) <- NULL

    outlist[[list.item.name]] <- newdf

  }

}
```

This produces:

```
> outlist
$`litter.2010`

1 lost pot pool
2   50  15   35

$lost.2010

1 pool pot lost
2   30  10   60

$bin.2010

1 collected uncollected
2        96           4

$uncollected.2010

1 litter burn dump
2     25   55   20

$collected.2010

1 litter dump recycle burn
2    3.7 54.3    30.0 12.0

$litter.2011

1 lost pot pool
2   50  15   35

$lost.2011

1 pool pot lost
2   30  10   60

$bin.2011

1 collected uncollected
2        96           4

$uncollected.2011

1 litter burn dump
2     25   55   20

$collected.2011

1 litter dump recycle burn
2    3.7 54.3    30.0 12.0

$litter.2012

1 lost pot pool
2   50  15   35

$lost.2012

1 pool pot lost
2   30  10   60

$bin.2012

1 collected uncollected
2        96           4

$uncollected.2012

1 litter burn dump
2     25   55   20

$collected.2012

1 litter dump recycle burn
2    3.7 54.3    30.0 12.0
```

Comment: Brilliant! this is exactly what I needed - thanks Grant, nothing that a good hammer can't fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Does calling `dlply()` twice provide the desired output?

```r
df1 <- dlply(df,.(year),function(x){
  x %>% select(-year) %>% 
    dlply(.,.(item))
  })

df1

$`2010`
$bin
  item        node value
1  bin   collected    96
2  bin uncollected     4

$collected
       item    node value
1 collected  litter   3.7
2 collected    dump  54.3
3 collected recycle  30.0
4 collected    burn  12.0

$litter
    item node value
1 litter lost    50
2 litter  pot    15
3 litter pool    35

$lost
  item node value
1 lost pool    30
2 lost  pot    10
3 lost lost    60
...

str(df1)
List of 3
 $ 2010:List of 5
  ..$ bin        :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ item : Factor w/ 5 levels "bin","collected",..: 1 1
  .. ..$ node : Factor w/ 9 levels "burn","collected",..: 2 9
  .. ..$ value: num [1:2] 96 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "item"
  ..$ collected  :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ item : Factor w/ 5 levels "bin","collected",..: 2 2 2 2
  .. ..$ node : Factor w/ 9 levels "burn","collected",..: 4 3 8 1
  .. ..$ value: num [1:4] 3.7 54.3 30 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "item"
  ..$ litter     :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ item : Factor w/ 5 levels "bin","collected",..: 3 3 3
  .. ..$ node : Factor w/ 9 levels "burn","collected",..: 5 7 6
  .. ..$ value: num [1:3] 50 15 35
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "item"
  ..$ lost       :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ item : Factor w/ 5 levels "bin","collected",..: 4 4 4
  .. ..$ node : Factor w/ 9 levels "burn","collected",..: 6 7 5
  .. ..$ value: num [1:3] 30 10 60
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "item"
  ..$ uncollected:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ item : Factor w/ 5 levels "bin","collected",..: 5 5 5
  .. ..$ node : Factor w/ 9 levels "burn","collected",..: 4 1 3
  .. ..$ value: num [1:3] 25 55 20
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "item"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "split" "list"
...
```

**EDIT**
Try using `spread()` first then passing that to the two `dlply()` calls. This gets a bit closer to your desired output, I think. You can probably modify the calls within `dlply()` to remove variables with `NA` values.

```r
df %>% spread(node,value) %>% dlply(.,.(year),function(x){
  x %>% select(-year) %>% 
    dlply(.,.(item))
})
$`2010`
$bin
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1  bin   NA        96   NA     NA   NA   NA  NA      NA           4

$collected
       item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 collected   12        NA 54.3    3.7   NA   NA  NA      30          NA

$litter
    item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 litter   NA        NA   NA     NA   50   35  15      NA          NA

$lost
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 lost   NA        NA   NA     NA   60   30  10      NA          NA

$uncollected
         item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 uncollected   55        NA   20     25   NA   NA  NA      NA          NA


$`2011`
$bin
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1  bin   NA        96   NA     NA   NA   NA  NA      NA           4

$collected
       item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 collected   12        NA 54.3    3.7   NA   NA  NA      30          NA

$litter
    item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 litter   NA        NA   NA     NA   50   35  15      NA          NA

$lost
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 lost   NA        NA   NA     NA   60   30  10      NA          NA

$uncollected
         item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 uncollected   55        NA   20     25   NA   NA  NA      NA          NA


$`2012`
$bin
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1  bin   NA        96   NA     NA   NA   NA  NA      NA           4

$collected
       item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 collected   12        NA 54.3    3.7   NA   NA  NA      30          NA

$litter
    item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 litter   NA        NA   NA     NA   50   35  15      NA          NA

$lost
  item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 lost   NA        NA   NA     NA   60   30  10      NA          NA

$uncollected
         item burn collected dump litter lost pool pot recycle uncollected
1 uncollected   55        NA   20     25   NA   NA  NA      NA          NA
```

Comment: Thanks @kstew! what I need is for the node names to be the variable names within the list item - like this 
```r 
$collected
  litter dump recycle burn
1    3.7 54.3      30   12
```

Comment: I have updated my post, perhaps this is closer to what you expect. Still unsure why you would want to transform your data this way, if it is already in a data frame.

Comment: The edit output doesn't look like your question output at all.